# How to edit the view of clock in the windows taskbar?

Tags: windows-xp

My clock in the taskbar is showing just the time and day name. How can I customize it to show the date as well?

I am using Windows XP Professional.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason,

I was using the windows classic style not the windows xp style in the appearance.

When i changed back to xp style, the date is showing beside the time and day name.

Comment: This requires your taskbar to be multiple lines though, right?

Comment: Nice work                .

Comment: @ Stefan Thyberg, no

Comment: In your screenshot your taskbar is multiple lines? If I take mine down to one row, only the time is shown.

Comment: @Amr ElGarhy, strange.. on my machine, I have to make it multiple lines!! Any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

The XP clock in classic mode does not support showing the date. There are 3rd party applications that can accomplish this though, such as [TClock.exe](http://www.rcis.co.za/dale/tclockex/index.htm).

Another alternative is [AlfaClock](http://www.alfasoftweb.com/alfaclock/) which has a lot of other functionality as well.

This works without having to make your taskbar span multiple rows, making it useful even for windows configurations which support showing the date.

Comment: Added some information so that it's no longer a duplicate.

Comment: both links are downed, unfortunately. I suspect that they wouldn't work with modern versions of Window, either.

Answer (score 1):

[TClock](http://homepage1.nifty.com/kazubon/tclock/) gives you this ability. As for the wrapping in the image below, I'm assuming that is caused by the width of the systray. Expanding that would likely put the date/time on one line.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you used a program to change or modify your taskbar (a Windows themes app for example)?  Try stretching the taskbar up to about 3x the normal height - is it still just time and day?